# Mobile Number Keypad Input with Dashes, Asterick, etc

Tags: ios, mobile, input, android-keypad, iphone-keypad

I thought I had the whole numeric keypad down and tested on ios 7. But I can't get the dashes, decimals or astericks button to appear.
Here is the code I thought would work:

```
<input type="number" pattern=[0-9]* inputmode=numeric name="rx1" id="rx1" class="single fldrequired" value=""/>
```

However, it does not give the option to have dashes, decimals, astericks, etc. I expected it to be in the lower left corner of the keypad, but no such luck. I've tried different variations such as:

```
<input type="text" pattern=[0-9]* name="rx1" id="rx1" class="single fldrequired" value=""/>
<input type="number" pattern="\d*" name="rx1" id="rx1" class="single fldrequired" value=""/>
<input type="text" pattern="\d*" name="rx1" id="rx1" class="single fldrequired" value=""/>
```

None of them have produced the button for the extra characters. So for now, I'm just using:

```
<input type="number" name="rx1" id="rx1" class="single fldrequired" value=""/>
```

Is this an ios 7 thing or am I just doing something completely wrong. I tried "tel" as well, but that wasn't really what I was looking.

Thanks.